# How do I convert a composite class into a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class called Large, which contains an instance of Small.

```
    class Small:
    s: str

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = "I am Small"

class Large:
    small: Small
    details: str

    def __init__(self):
        self.small = Small()
        self.details = "Details???"
```

when I call the class and try to look at its dictionary, it looks broken

```
large = Large()
print(large.__dict__)
{'small': <__main__.Small object at 0x1110e2e50>, 'details': 'Details???'}
```

how do I force the small attribute to a dictionary also?

Comment: Do you understand `__dict__` is the instance namespace? It doesn't "convert" the object to a dictionary. It doesn't look *broken at all*, this is exactly what you should expect to see, the `"small"` attribute has a `Small` object. Note, if you *modify* that dictionary, you *modify the instance*, because it *is the instance namespace*

Comment: Ok my understanding of __dict__ is wrong. What is the correct way of converting an instance of large to a dictionary?

Comment: You have to write that logic yourself.

Comment: fair enough, I was thinking there might be a builtin support for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like:

```
>>> class Small:
    def __init__(self):
        self.s = "I am Small"

        
>>> class Large:
    def __init__(self):
        self.small = Small()
        self.details = "Details???"

        
>>> def object_to_dict(instance):
    output = {}
    if not isinstance(instance, dict):
        items = instance.__dict__.items()
    else:
        items = instance.items()
    for key,value in items:
        if isinstance(value, Small):
            output[key] = object_to_dict(value.__dict__)
        else:
            output[key] = value
    return output

>>> large = Large()
>>> large.littleSmall = Small()
>>> print(object_to_dict(large))
{'small': {'s': 'I am Small'}, 'details': 'Details???', 'littleSmall': {'s': 'I am Small'}}
```

But it only get `__dict__` for a Small object if there is more classes you should add them in isinstance() function as tuple on second argument

Comment: thank you so much to my country man, very elegant answer